# C# Winforms use AutoGenerateColumns in DataGridView with a CheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I use a DataGridView with AutoGenerateColumns but would like to display one of the columns (integer) as a CheckBoxColum, is there an easy way or do I have to set AutoGenerateColumns off and add all of the columns manually ?
Changing the cellTemplate causes a error

```
dgvKlanten.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvKlanten.DataSource = dsKlantenBeheer.Tables["Klanten"];
dgvKlanten.Columns["Nieuwsbrief"].Width = 70;
//dgvKlanten.Columns["Nieuwsbrief"].CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
```

Comment: Wouldn't the field need to be a `Boolean` for that to happen automatically?  `Integer` and checkbox do not equate.

Comment: Remove the column from the DataGridView, and then re-add it with the correct specification after the auto-generate step?

Comment: @DonBoitnott: i use SqlServer and don't see a type boolean, what type shoudl i use in my db ?

Comment: I believe you want `Bit`.  With that incoming datatype, you should automatically get a checkbox column.

Comment: @dash: how do i bind this new column to the integer field ?

Comment: @peter - set the `ColumnName` property to be the same name as the Field you want to bind it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just hide the auto-generated column for that column, then manually add a checkbox column to take its place.

On a side note, I'm assuming this integer column only supports values zero and one?  Since this is an integer and not a boolean like the checkbox expects, you may have to use the grid events, such as CellFormatting, to read the value from the data source and set the checkbox accordingly, but I'm not sure.  Or, if this is an object, you could expose the integer value as a boolean using another, custom property.  No matter what, you are likely going to need to do more work than simply adding a checkbox column and pointing it to the datasource column.

Comment: i use SqlServer and don't see a type boolean, what type shoudl i use in my db ?

Comment: Bit = Boolean in SQL Server.

Comment: If you change the DB type to Bit, then the autogenerated column will be a checkbox.

Comment: ok, i'll try, but if i follow the remove/add road, how do i bind this new column to the integer field ?

Comment: Each DataGridViewColumn has a property called DataPropertyName.  Set this name to the name of the property in the DataSource.  However, making the DB column a bit type is really the most correct way to go.